# Python - pickup data based on a list of values or conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set that has 9 columns, and I managed to extract two of the columns using pandas (Thank you Stack members for your help before!). Now, my question is: I have a list of values that will be used to pickup from the data set and extract the corresponding values. The extracted data set looks like:

```
Exp. m/z    Intensity
1000        2000
2000        3000
3000        4000
4000        5000
```

and so on (there are about 500+ rows for each data set). The list used for pickup looks like:

```
mass
1200
1300
```

and so on (about 200 rows for the pickup list). Each mass value will be used to calculate the upper and lower bins, and they will be used to pickup the Exp. m/z values from the data set. So, for example, mass 1200 will be calculated as 1250 (upper) and 1150 (lower), and whatever falls within this range from the data set will be picked up, and their corresponding Intensity values are what I want. If none are picked up, I want the result to be empty value if possible as I believe 0 values affect average and other statistical analysis.

Below is my code, where file is the data set and pickupfile is the pickup list:

from pandas import DataFrame

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    file = 'C09.xls'
    pickupfile = 'pickuplist.xlsx'

    xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
    pl = pd.ExcelFile(pickupfile)

    plist = pd.read_excel(xl)
    pickuplist = pd.read_excel(pl)

    cmass = plist['Exp. m/z']
    height = plist['Intensity']


    plistcollect = pd.concat([cmass, height], axis=1)


    ppm = 150

    peak1upper = round(pickuplist*(1+ppm/1000000),4)

    peak1lower = round(pickuplist*(1-ppm/1000000),4)

    pickup = plistcollect[((plistcollect['Exp. m/z']>peak1lower) & (plistcollect['Exp. m/z'] < peak1upper))]
    print(pickup['Intensity'])
```

When I execute this code, I get an error message: ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not float64.  I do understand my data set are floating values, so do you guys have some hints or tips/recommendations?

Thank you so much!!

EDIT:
Forgot to mention that my data and the two limits (peak1lower & peak1upper) are float64 types.

I also tried the pickup with isin like:

```
    pickup = plistcollect[plistcollect.isin(np.arange(peak1lower,peak1upper))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to make a new DataFrame with the values from the pickuplist as index, and from plist as columns

```
matches = pd.DataFrame(index=pickup['mass'], columns = plist.set_index(list(plist.columns)).index, dtype=bool)
```

Then populate this DataFrame as needed if for example you can only be 150ppm from the target than you can use `abs` to make this two-sided comparison

```
ppm = 150
for index, exp_mass, intensity in plist.itertuples():
    matches[exp_mass] = abs(matches.index - exp_mass) / matches.index < ppm / 1e6
```

This gives something like this

```
Exp. m/z    1000    2000    3000    4000
Intensity   2000    3000    4000    5000
mass                
1000    True    False   False   False
1200    False   False   False   False
1300    False   False   False   False
```

Which you can easily condense with a dict comprehension

```
results = {i: list(s.index[s]) for i, s in matches.iterrows()}
```

Which returns a dict entry for each row in `pickuplist` all the matches in `plist` in the form of a tuple `(Exp. m/z, Intensity)` like this

```
{1000: [(1000, 2000)], 1200: [], 1300: []}
```

If you only want the `(Exp. m/z, Intensity)` tuples, you can do this

```
results2 = {key for key, value in matches.any().iteritems() if value}
```

this give this `set`

```
{(1000, 2000)}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! print(matches) yields Exp. m/z values on top and Intensity values at the bottom, followed by a table showing True's and False's. Is there a way to access the Exp. m/z and Intensity values? I tried using matches[1] but that gave an error

Comment: And I am not sure how I can print the dict comprehension. Tried print(i) but said i is not defined. The code itself doesn't give any error.

Comment: Also, just realized that my first comment is a bit off. I now understand the table format now. Now I want to extract the headers (Exp. m/z and Intensity) for the mass values marked with True. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I adapted my answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Maarten! Sorry for my bothering, but is there a way to access individual values from the (Exp. m/z, Intensity) tuples? I tried doing pickup_mass = results2['exp_mass'] and others but to no avail (said set object is not subscriptable). I apologize if I am asking a stupid/redundant question.

Comment: `matches.any().reset_index()` returns a DataFrame with the information you seem to need. `matches.any().reset_index()[matches.any().values]` gives only the matches

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Seems to be working perfectly. Now I am off to find a way to do this for a collection of different xls files. Thanks again for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one condition while indexing a dataframe, all the conditions have be within another bracket together.

```
plistcollect[(plistcollect['Exp. m/z']>peak1lower) & (plistcollect['Exp. m/z'] < peak1upper)]
```

should be

```
plistcollect[((plistcollect['Exp. m/z']>peak1lower) & (plistcollect['Exp. m/z'] < peak1upper))]
```

Edit: Since you need to perform it on every element, you have to do something like this:

```
limit_df = pd.DataFrame([peak1lower['Exp. m/z'],peak1upper['Exp. m/z']], index=['lower','upper']).T
filtered_df = limit_df.apply(lambda x: ((plistcollect['Exp. m/z'] > x.lower) & (plistcollect['Exp. m/z'] < x.upper)), axis=1)
```

filtered_df will give you a boolean DataFrame, each row will have True, False corresponding to DataFrame entry that fall within the given element of mass list.

The simpler way can be to save the file individually:

```
def filter_df(x):
    plistcollect[((plistcollect['Exp. m/z'] > x.lower) & (plistcollect['Exp. m/z'] < x.upper))].to_csv("test_%s.csv"%x.name)

limit_df.apply(lambda x: filter_df(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I inserted the brackets but it still gives me the same error message. I also forgot to mention that peak1upper and peak1lower are also float64 types. The error message is: ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not float64

Comment: In this edit you posted: pickup = plistcollect[plistcollect.isin(np.arange(peak1lower,peak1upper))], does it still give the same error? Try:
plistcollect[plistcollect['Exp. m/z'].isin(np.arange(peak1lower,peak1upper))]

Comment: Now it is saying: TypeError: must be real number, not DataFrame. Should I be doing this with for and if loops?

Comment: I tried a similar dataset and it works. I think the best way for you would be to debug it one by one. Check if (plistcollect['Exp. m/z']>peak1lower) executes or if it gives the error. Similarly for the other condition. Also print your series and the limits to see everything is OK or not.

Comment: Oh wait a second. Your peak1lower and peak1upper are DataFrame? Shouldn't it be a constant float value? That's what the new error is!

Comment: I will modify the answer.

Comment: I think they are also series. The pickupfile contains a list of mass values that I imported using pandas as well. peak1upper and lower calculations were applied to all the items in the series. So in a nutshell, I am picking up the data using a list of values with some calculations on the list.

Comment: Sorry I meant DataFrame like you said in your answer. So I can't do calculations on a dataframe, and then use the resulting calculation numbers to collect values from the data similar to binning?

Comment: Ofcourse you can. Correct me if I am wrong, you want to do the selection operation for every element in your mass list? If this is the case, you have to perform apply/map operation on every element, calculate real-valued upper and lower limit for each element, filter the plistcollect and store the filtered list.

Comment: Yes that's pretty much what I want at this moment. So for each element in my mass list, I can calculate upper and lower limits, and whatever data points fall within these ranges, I want to 'tag' or pick them up. Sorry, I am very new to Python and programming in general so I am a bit lost on apply/map operation (though I've heard about them)