# pandas DataFrame - how to group and tag rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large set of data that I want to extract two columns, which I managed to do so with the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os


pickupfile = 'pickuplist.xls'

path = os.chdir('some path')
files = os.listdir(path)
files_xls = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'xls']

df = pd.DataFrame()
pl = pd.ExcelFile(pickupfile)
pickuplist = pd.read_excel(pl)

df = [pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1')[['Exp. m/z','Intensity']] for f in files_xls]

plistcollect = pd.concat(df, keys=files_xls)\
                 .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)\
                 .rename_axis('Tag')\
                 .reset_index()
```

Each file from pk list folder contains 10 columns, and the code above pulls two columns from the file into plistcollect dataframe. The downside for me is that the file pulling iteration appends the data to the bottom of the previous data. A data looks like:

```
Number    Exp. m/z    Intensity
1         1013.33     1000
2         1257.52     2000
```

and so on, and with append:

```
Number    Exp. m/z    Intensity
1         1013.33     1000
2         1257.52     2000
3         1013.35     3000
4         1257.61     4000
```

where 1~2 are from the first file, and 3~4 are from the second file, and so on. Each file has varying number of rows or indices (i.e. file 1 has 400 rows, file 2 has 501 rows, etc.), which is causing some problems down the line for my code. So the question is, **is there a way to tag each file so that when the files are iterated for appending to plistcollect, the rows of plistcollect DataFrame are tagged with the names of the files, so that I can perform binning for each tag?**

---

As a side note, after defining plistcollect, I perform matching by:

```
ppm = 150

matches = pd.DataFrame(index=pickuplist['mass'], columns=plistcollect.set_index(list(plistcollect.columns)).index, dtype=bool)

for index, findex, exp_mass, intensity in plistcollect.itertuples():
    matches[findex, exp_mass] = abs(matches.index - exp_mass) / matches.index < ppm / 1e6


results = {i: list(s.index[s]) for i, s in matches.iterrows()}
results2 = {key for key, value in matches.any().iteritems() if value}
results3 = matches.any().reset_index()[matches.any().values]
```

which picks up those Exp. m/z values that fall within ppm differences (150 ppm), still in the same format as plistcollect. Then I do binning with np.digitize by:

```
bins = np.arange(900, 3000, 1)

groups = results3.groupby(np.digitize(results3['Exp. m/z'], bins))


stdev = groups['Intensity'].std()
average = groups['Intensity'].mean()
CV = stdev/average*100



resulttable = pd.concat([groups['Exp. m/z'].mean(),average,CV], axis=1)


resulttable.columns.values[1] = 'Average'
resulttable.columns.values[2] = 'CV'


resulttable.to_excel('test.xls', index=False)
```

This gives me what I want in terms of raw data analysis like (please note that the numbers for this table do not correspond to the example table above):

```
Exp. m/z    Average     CV
1013.32693  582361.5354 13.49241757
1257.435414 494927.0904 12.45206038
```

However, I want to normalize the intensity values for EACH data file, so I thought that the binning should be done on the separate data for each file. Hence, why I am asking if there is a way to tag the rows for plistcollect with regard to each corresponding file. Also please note that the matching process must be done before normalization. The normalization would be to divide each intensity value by the sum of the intensity values from the same data file. Using the example Table above, the normalized intensity for 1013.33 would be: 1000/(1000+2000), and that for 1013.35 would be: 3000/(3000+4000).

I can calculate the sum of all the values within each bin with no problem, but I can't seem to find a way to find the sum of intensity values between bins that correspond to where the values have come from the appended files.

**EDIT:**

I edited the code to reflect the answer, along with adding 'findex' to the matches dataframe. Now the results3 dataframe seems to contain the file names as tags. groups dataframe also seems to have Tag values as well. The question is, how do I designate/group by the tag names?

```
filetags = groups['Tag']
resulttable = pd.concat([filetags, groups['Exp. m/z'].mean(), average, CV], axis=1)
```

produces error message of: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object.

**Edit2:**
The pickuplist.xls file contains a column named 'mass' that simply has a list of Exp. m/z values that I use to pickup the obtained Exp. m/z values from the appended files (where ppm 150 comes in, so those Exp. m/z values that fall within 150 ppm difference (abs(mass - mass_from_file)/mass*1000000 = 150). the pickuplist.xls looks like:

```
mass
1013.34
1079.3757
1095.3706
1136.3972
1241.4285
1257.4234
```

These are what I call known pickup list, and each file may or may not contain these mass values. And the matches definition actually also came from one of the kind users of Stack Overflow. It is used to iterate over the plistcollect, and selects those Exp. m/z values that fall within 150 ppm difference from 'mass'.

Comment: Waht is `print (type(filetags))` before `resulttable = pd.concat([filetags, groups['Exp. m/z'].mean(), average, CV], axis=1)` ?

Comment: it says pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy. print(filetags) after resulttable doesn't produce error, so there must be something off with how I am concatenating filetags to resulttable.

Comment: I think you miss some aggregate function like `groups['Tag'].mean()` or `groups['Tag'].std()`

Comment: hmm the tag values are string values like C09.xls - names of the files.

Comment: OK, I would like help you with your another code, but code from `ppm = 150` to `results3 = matches.any().reset_index()[matches.any().values]` dont understand. Also I have no data form column `mass`... Can you explain more and add some data samples?

Comment: edited the post. the matches lines came from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44511573/python-pickup-data-based-on-a-list-of-values-or-conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use parameter `keys` in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
dfs = []
for f in files_xls:
    dfs = pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1')[['Exp. m/z','Intensity']]
    dfs.append(data)
```

It is same as:

```
dfs = [pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1')[['Exp. m/z','Intensity']] for f in files_xls]
```

---

```
plistcollect = pd.concat(dfs, keys=files_xls) \
                 .reset_index(level=1, drop=True) \
                 .rename_axis('Tag') \
                 .reset_index()
print (plistcollect)
         Tag  Exp.m/z  Intensity
0  test1.xls  1013.33       1000
1  test1.xls  1257.52       2000
2  test2.xls  1013.35       3000
3  test2.xls  1257.61       4000
```

EDIT:

I think I got it. Need `Tag` column add to matches first and then groupby by `np.digitize` with `Tag` column:

```
print (plist)
         Tag  Exp. m/z  Intensity
0  test1.xls      1000       2000
1  test1.xls      1000       1500
2  test1.xls      2000       3000
3  test2.xls      3000       4000
4  test2.xls      4000       5000
5  test2.xls      4000       5500

pickup = pd.DataFrame({'mass':[1000,1200,1300, 4000]})
print (pickup)
   mass
0  1000
1  1200
2  1300
3  4000

matches = pd.DataFrame(index=pickup['mass'], 
                       columns = plist.set_index(list(plist.columns)).index, 
                       dtype=bool)

ppm = 150
for index, tags, exp_mass, intensity in plist.itertuples():
    matches[(tags, exp_mass)] = abs(matches.index - exp_mass) / matches.index < ppm / 1e6

print (matches)
Tag       test1.xls               test2.xls              
Exp. m/z       1000          2000      3000   4000       
Intensity      2000   1500   3000      4000   5000   5500
mass                                                     
1000           True   True  False     False  False  False
1200          False  False  False     False  False  False
1300          False  False  False     False  False  False
4000          False  False  False     False   True   True
```

---

```
results3 = matches.any().reset_index(name='a')[matches.any().values]
print (results3)
         Tag  Exp. m/z  Intensity     a
0  test1.xls      1000       2000  True
1  test1.xls      1000       1500  True
4  test2.xls      4000       5000  True
5  test2.xls      4000       5500  True

bins = np.arange(900, 3000, 1)
groups = results3.groupby([np.digitize(results3['Exp. m/z'], bins), 'Tag'])

resulttable = groups.agg({'Intensity':['mean','std'], 'Exp. m/z': 'mean'})
resulttable.columns = resulttable.columns.map('_'.join)
resulttable['CV'] = resulttable['Intensity_std'] / resulttable['Intensity_mean'] * 100
d = {'Intensity_mean':'Average','Exp. m/z_mean':'Exp. m/z'}
resulttable = resulttable.reset_index().rename(columns=d) \
                          .drop(['Intensity_std', 'level_0'],axis=1)
print (resulttable)
         Tag  Average  Exp. m/z         CV
0  test1.xls     1750      1000  20.203051
1  test2.xls     5250      4000   6.734350
```

Comment: the plistcollect line seems to produce an error saying unexpected indent at .reset_index(level=1, drop=True).  So I removed the ')' from pd.concat(dfs, keys=files_xls) and added the closing parenthesis at the end (.reset_index()), which now is giving me an error message of list object has no attribute 'reset_index'.

Comment: you can add `\` or create one long line, then it works.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It is simply amazing how you can come up with this code when I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out the solutions.   In any case, this seems to group results3 dataframe by Tags as intended. Then when resulttable is made, average, stdev, and CV don't seem to be calculated. Also, I need to divide each element (Intensity values) for each file by the sum of the intensity values after matching. So for test1.xls, I would be summing the intensity values, then divide each intensity by the sum. Is there a way to do so? I apologize if I am asking too much.

Comment: I tried removing 'Tag' part for the group groupby step (that contains np.digitize), and that did the calculations, but now the tags were gone as expected.

Comment: Glad can help. I have idea. Can we communicate via email? My email is in my profile.

Comment: Because My main problem is I am not sure if understand what you need exactly. But this really helped me - use my sample data from edit and add desired output. Now I am offline, only on phone, so easier is communicate via email. I believe solition is really close.... Thanks.